# why I can not get the elements from appending one list into another

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, empty-list

I was asked to append one list into another empty list (with some changes in the original list)
I tried the following code it shows a wrong output

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames=[]
change= [n.lower() for n in names]
for n in names:
    username=(n.replace(' ','_'))
usernames.append(username)
print (usernames)
```

the expected output :

```
joey_tribbiani
monica_geller
chandler_bing
phoebe_buffay
```

what I get:

```
['Phoebe_Buffay']
```

Comment: You need to align your append statement. It is going out of for loop

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way to implement is using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Try this:

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = [n.lower().replace(' ','_') for n in names]
print (usernames)
```

Now, let's jump to your code. The problem lies at the line `username=(n.replace(' ','_'))`. In each iteration, you are redefining the variable and after the last iteration of the for loop, `username` points to the last element in your list.

May be that's just indentation issue and you wanted `append` operation in each iteration of the for loop but accidentally forgot to indent it properly . I have removed `username` variable and moved the `append` under for loop. Try this:

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []
for n in names:
    usernames.append(n.lower().replace(' ','_'))
print(usernames)
```

Output:

```
['joey_tribbiani', 'monica_geller', 'chandler_bing', 'phoebe_buffay']
```